# KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException not thrown when a new fingerprint is added

Tags: android, encryption, fingerprint

I have CipherUtils class which is responsible for creating the cipher which is taken from [the google dialog sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog)

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.app.Application
import android.app.KeyguardManager
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager
import android.os.Build
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec
import android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import androidx.core.content.edit
import java.io.IOException
import java.security.*
import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.inject.Inject


class CipherUtils @Inject constructor(
    val application: Application,
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) {
    internal val DEFAULT_KEY_NAME = "ubit_key"
    private val KEY = "fingerInvalid"

    private var mKeyStore: KeyStore? = null
    private var mKeyGenerator: KeyGenerator? = null
    private var defaultCipher: Cipher

    init {

        try {
            mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        } catch (e: KeyStoreException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyStore", e)
        }

        try {
            mKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator
                .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyGenerator", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchProviderException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyGenerator", e)
        }

        try {
            defaultCipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7
            )
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchPaddingException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of Cipher", e)
        }

        init()
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun init() {
        val keyguardManager = getSystemService(application,KeyguardManager::class.java)
        val fingerprintManager = getSystemService(application,FingerprintManager::class.java)

        if (!keyguardManager!!.isKeyguardSecure()) {
            // Show a message that the user hasn't set up a fingerprint or lock screen.
            return
        }

        // Now the protection level of USE_FINGERPRINT permission is normal instead of dangerous.
        // See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_FINGERPRINT
        // The line below prevents the false positive inspection from Android Studio
        // noinspection ResourceType
        if (!fingerprintManager!!.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
            // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.

            return
        }
        createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true)
    }

    /**
     * Creates a symmetric key in the Android Key Store which can only be used after the user has
     * authenticated with fingerprint.
     *
     * @param keyName the name of the key to be created
     * @param invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment if `false` is passed, the created key will not
     * be invalidated even if a new fingerprint is enrolled.
     * The default value is `true`, so passing
     * `true` doesn't change the behavior
     * (the key will be invalidated if a new fingerprint is
     * enrolled.). Note that this parameter is only valid if
     * the app works on Android N developer preview.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun createKey(keyName: String, invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment: Boolean) {
        // The enrolling flow for fingerprint. This is where you ask the user to set up fingerprint
        // for your flow. Use of keys is necessary if you need to know if the set of
        // enrolled fingerprints has changed.
        try {
            mKeyStore?.load(null)
            // Set the alias of the entry in Android KeyStore where the key will appear
            // and the constrains (purposes) in the constructor of the Builder

            val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                keyName,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
            )
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                // of the key
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)

            // This is a workaround to avoid crashes on devices whose API level is < 24
            // because KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment is only
            // visible on API level +24.
            // Ideally there should be a compat library for KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder but
            // which isn't available yet.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                builder.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment)
            }
            mKeyGenerator?.init(builder.build())
            mKeyGenerator?.generateKey()
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: CertificateException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the [Cipher] instance with the created key in the
     * [.createKey] method.
     *
     * @param keyName the key name to init the cipher
     * @return `true` if initialization is successful, `false` if the lock screen has
     * been disabled or reset after the key was generated, or if a fingerprint got enrolled after
     * the key was generated.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun initCipher(cipher: Cipher, keyName: String): Boolean {
        try {
            mKeyStore?.load(null)
            val key = mKeyStore?.getKey(keyName, null) as SecretKey
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
            return true
        } catch (e: KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException) {
            return false
        } catch (e: KeyStoreException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: CertificateException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: UnrecoverableKeyException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: InvalidKeyException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        }

    }

}
```

When a new fingerprint is enrolled, with running `initCipher`, I expect to get `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` but it returns true. what am I missing and how to fix this to get to know when a new fingerprint is added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched a lot and found The answer [in a comment in issues](https://github.com/android/security/issues/9#issuecomment-528901903)

> This sample creates a new key in onCreate, so if you launch the sample app after you add a new fingerprint, KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is not thrown because at the time the key is created, a set of fingerprints include the new created one.

> If you want to test that KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException, please try to add a new fingerprint while keeping the app open.

But I want this feature to work when app closes. So added a few lines of code before creating a new key, I check if there is a key before and don't create it if it exists.

```
/**
 * returns current saved key
 */
private fun getCurrentKey(keyName: String): Key? {
    keyStore?.load(null)
    return keyStore?.getKey(keyName, null)
}
```

and replace this with the create key part of the code

```
/**
 * Only if the key is not created, Create a new key
 */
private fun createKeyIfNotExists() {
    if (getCurrentKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME) == null) {
        createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true)
    }
}
```